# How can i add new property (photo) to user in node.js?

Tags: node.js, react-fullstack

[`userModel.js`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE7Ha.png)
[userRoute.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7vZs.png)`a`
[licenseMiddelware.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD9k5.png)

i want to add new property (photo) to the users in database [mondoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1SL6.png)
but when i run my code its add new section in users (mongoDB) contains only the photo like that [problem in DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya2Kt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `const photo = req.file.filename`. But you need to use `req.file.path` instead to get the file path, refer to `multer` documentation: https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information

Comment: thanks , but it's not my main problem i just want to add the (photo) property into the user object , but its showed like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya2Kt.png

Comment: you can implement Sagar's answer for this, but to do that you'll have to pass a user identifier in req to update an existing user after authenticating the user, so the following middleware can use it

Answer (score 0):

You are using `User.create({photo})` which will create new document.

To update(add property to) one document use `User.findOneAndUpdate({...filters}, {photo})`. filters could be `let filters={username:"talaat"};`

To update on all objects `User.updateMany({}, { photo });`